# Angular getter on page

Tags: angular, typescript

I wanted something like this C# code:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    public int SomeInt {get;set;}
    public string StatusDescription 
    {
        if (SomeInt == 0}
        {
             return "Zero";
        }
        else 
        {
            return "Not Zero";
        }
    }
}
```

So that on my page, I can do something like this:

```html
<div class="col" *ngFor="let someClass of allMyClasses">
<mat-card class="example-card mt-2">
    <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
        <label>{{someClass.statusDescription}}</label>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
</div>
```

My attempt at resolving this was:

```ts
export class myClass{
    someInt: number;
    get statusDescription(): string
    {
        return "Status";
    }
}
```

My typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { myClass } from '../models/myClass';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing',
  templateUrl: './myClass.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myClass.component.css']
})
export class MyClassComponent implements OnInit {

  allMyClasses: Array<myClass> = new Array<myClass>();
  constructor(private myClassService: MyClassService  ) 
  { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  fetchMyClasses()
  {
    this.myClassService.getMyClasses().then(
    (results) => this.allMyClasses= results
    );
  }

}
```

MyClassService. I'm sure this piece works, because I can see the data being pulled from here, and other properties being displayed on the page/template.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { myClass } from '../models/myClass';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyClassService {

  baseUrl: string = "https://localhost:44313/api/myClass/";
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getMyClasses()
  {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}getMyClasses`;
    const result = this.httpClient.get<Array<myClass>>(url, {}).toPromise();
    return result;
  }

}
```

However, when my page renders, it does not display "Status", and no errors or warnings in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You just need `{{ statusDescription }}`. And no, @terahertz; it's an *accessor*, you don't need to call it.

Comment: @terahertz, thanks for your comment. Tried both with and without the parenthesis, same result.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. Removed the "someclass.", same result, no error or warning.

Comment: Wait, sorry, that's not the component class? Please give a [mcve] that shows how this all fits together. Are you sure allMyClasses is an array of myClass instances, not just objects? Any chance they're coming from HttpClient and you've confused the generic typing with actual casting or conversion?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I've added my TS to the question. If I change my code to {{someClass.SomeInt}}, it shows the value of that property, so I know the allMyClasses is populated, and there is data to work with. For this reason, I've left the service out of code; the problem is clearly not in fetching the data.

Comment: ...so what does MyClassService do? *Is* it using HttpClient? Does this work if you just set `allMyClasses: myClass[] = [new myClass()]`? Again, **are you sure they're actually myClass instances**, not just objects with the SomeInt property?

Comment: I'd also suspect that these are not actual instances of MyClass but simple objects (maybe retrieved from an http call?) and thus don't have the accessor. I'd instanceof them to verify this.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, updated the question with the service. And yes, Im 100% that it's populated. I'm not setting the values anywhere else.

Comment: It's 100% populated, but **not with myClass instances**. The generic typing, documented in https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response, **does not cause casting or conversion**; it's just a hint. If you want myClass instances, **you need to create them** from the plain objects the client gives you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of most of the questions I linked from https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25401

Comment: @WynDiesel, check my answer :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe, read through that now, and it seems exactly like what I'm experiencing. Typescript's "soft typing" is one of the biggest things I'm struggling with coming from something as strict as C#. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is how you create the elements of allMyClasses. If you write, e.g.

```
allMyClasses:myClass[]=[new myClass(),new myClass()];
```

Works perfectly. I supouse you has a problem when create the list

NOTE you can use some like

```
   cont class=Object.assign(new myClass(),{someInt:3})

   //or, e.g.
   this.allMyClasses.push(Object.assign(new myClass(),{someInt:3}))
```

To create an object myClass with both "properties":, someInt and statusDescription

**Update** so, if you has a list

```
this.myClassService.getMyClasses().then(
    (results) => this.allMyClasses= results.map(x=>Object.assign(new myClass(),x))
    );
```

NOTE: Why is the reason to convert to promise? For me has no sense

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-npxowm?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score -1):

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  private _statusDescription: string;

  get statusDescription(): string
    {
        return this._statusDescription = "Success";
    }

}
```

In template

```
<label>{{statusDescription}}</label>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4susrc

This is approach its not same like what asked but using this can solve issue.

Answer (score -2):

If you are useing VSCode i recomment using the Angular language service extension to get autocompletin in your html.

https://angular.io/guide/language-service

Always create new components with the angular cli. They will make sure that your components ts file and html file are tied in together.

e.g.

```
ng generate component testComponent
```

Your class is missing the @component annotation. The cli will auto generate this. If there is no annotation the class doesn't know that it should be a component. The files will be linked here.

Just try the cli generate to create this kind of file.

e.g.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'testComponent',
  templateUrl: './testComponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testComponent.component.scss']
})
```

https://angular.io/cli/generate

If you are calling a function in the html file do it like this:

```
<label>{{this.statusDescription()}}</label>
```

and in the ts like this file:

```
statusDescription(): string
{
    return "Status";
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend re-reading the question, rather than assuming voters haven't read your answer; this doesn't correspond at all to what the OP's asking.

Comment: The code has changed quite a bit. Now it's a promise problem.

Comment: It's absolutely not a promise problem.